# Validation of a user registration request should return 200 or 400

Tags: http, http-status-codes

The client sends a perfectly valid request for a user registration, e.g. username & password.

The server finds out that the username is already taken. What's the correct return status - 200 with an error message, or 400? The spec says:

> 400 implies that something was wrong with the request.
>   The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status
>   code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request
>   due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g.,
>   malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or
>   deceptive request routing).

But technically there's nothing wrong with the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is 'wrong' is that the request was intended to create a new user, but that failed because the username was already taken. This is definitely in the category 'client error'. Rather than seeing 'client error' as 'there is a bug', it's better to think of it was 'for one reason or another the request failed, and it's up to the client to make a correction'.

A typical error code for this specific situation might be `409 Conflict`.

If you sent back `200`, the client *should* perceive the result as "My request completed successfully", which is definitely not the case here.

Comment: Thank you. Will mark as answer. It's pretty clear when you explain it this way.

Comment: @HristoYankov awesome!